# How to display list returned to strongly typed partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form with a lookup.  I want to display the results of the lookup in the form so the user can select a result and then it would populate a field on the form (to be submitted with the form).  I have a partial view in the form with the search box.  That passes a string (pacupc) to the controller.  However, I don't know how to display the list that's being return to the partial view.
In my controller:

```
PriceAssociationLookup pacRep = new PriceAssociationLookup();

return PartialView("_PacSearchResultsPartial", pacRep.GetPacs(pacupc));
```

definition for GetPacs in class:

```
IEnumerable<IPriceAssociationLookupRepository> IPriceAssociationLookupRepository.GetPacs(string upc)
{
    using (PortalDataEntities entities = new PortalDataEntities())
    {
        var priceAssociationLookups = (from priceassociationlookup in entities.PriceAssociationLookups
                                       where priceassociationlookup.Upc == upc
                                       select priceassociationlookup).ToList();

        return priceAssociationLookups;
    }

}
```

and the partial view the lookup results are being sent to:

```
@model List<Portal.BusinessModel.Entities.PriceAssociationLookup>
@{
    //How to display the list of results?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply loop them like this:

```
@model List<Portal.BusinessModel.Entities.PriceAssociationLookup>
@foreach(var price in Model)
{
    @price.Upc
}
```

You can output any of your properties by using the `@price.Property` notation.

Please note if you are posting the items back you need to use a for loop and index them.